# Remove child component on click of link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am teaching myself react at the moment, I have a component that looks at the state and when a new item is added it appends a child component to itself. What I am now trying to do is remove the added child component via a click. However I cannot seem to get the natural event of a link to stop, if I do `e.preventDefault()` I get preventDefault is not a function of undefined.

Below is my code,

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InvoiceForm from './InvoiceForm';
import InvoiceItemForm from './InvoiceItemForm';

class GenerateInvoice extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      invoice: {
        items : []
      }
    };

    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.invoice.items.length; i += 1) {
      children.push(
        <InvoiceItemForm 
          key={i} 
          number={i}
          remove={this.removeItem} />
      );
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <a href="" onClick={this.onAddChild}>Add New Item</a>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }

  removeItem = (e, itemIndex) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("..removing...");
    // let invoice = this.state.invoice;
    // let updatedItems = this.state.invoice.items.splice(index, 1); //remove element
    // let updateInvoice = { ...invoice, items:updatedItems}
    // this.setState({ invoice }); //update state
  }

  onAddChild = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let invoice = this.state.invoice;
    // creates an updated version of the items without changing the original value
    let updatedItems = invoice.items.push({ 'id': 'INV001' });
    // creates a new version of the invoice with the updated items
    let updateInvoice = { ...invoice, items: updatedItems };
    // update the invoice on the state to the new version
    this.setState({ invoice });
  }


}
```

export default GenerateInvoice;

child component

```
    import React from 'react';

const InvoiceItemForm = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Hello {props.number}</p>
      <a href="" onClick={props.remove(props.number)}>Remove</a>
    </div>
  )
}

export default InvoiceItemForm;
```

and a link to my sandbox,

https://codesandbox.io/s/0qx9w1qrwv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `InvoiceItemForm` component, `onClick={props.remove(props.number)}`, only here you have the reference to the event object.

You can change to to something like:

```
onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  props.remove(props.number);
}}
```

EDIT:

If you'd like to avoid creating a function each render, you can use something like:

```
class InvoiceItemForm extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.remove(props.number);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Hello {this.props.number}</p>
        <a href="" onClick={this.handleClick}>Remove</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This maybe where I have come confused does this create a new function on each re-render and thus is inefficient?

Comment: You're right. See my edit. I have to say that in my opinion creating a new function each render is not that bad, avoiding it is a micro optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the index of the item to remove directly to the `removeItem` method.

Refactoring your render method:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <a href="" onClick={this.onAddChild}>Add New Item</a>
      {this.state.invoice.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <InvoiceItemForm
            key={index}
            number={index}
            remove={this.removeItem.bind(null, index)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will bind the index as the *first* argument to the removeItem function being passed in the props, while leaving the object binding untouched (so the context for the method remains the GenerateInvoice component. When the event is passed by the event handler, it will show up as the second argument.

So the handler definition should be:

```
removeItem(index, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...your removal code here...
}
```

And finally the super simple event handling in the child component:

```
<a href="" onClick={props.remove}>Remove</a>
```

Although I would use a `<button>` element instead to remove the whole default event handling & propagation altogether. `<a>` should be used exclusively for navigating content.